# VueJS Add up the values of inputs that are populated with backend data values after the component data is loaded and backend data is fetched?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a table that gets populated with inputs that are held within table cells. No matter how many inputs are retrieved, these particular inputs all have the same class. I need to find a way to target the values of each of these inputs, add those up, and then place that value into another input after the backend data has been fetched upon component load/mount. I can do this with vanilla JS and jquery, but I apparently need to go a different route with VueJS and this data being fetched. How can I achieve this in VueJS?

HTML EXAMPLE

```
<input class=".inputs" value="2"></input>
<input class=".inputs" value="2"></input>
<input class=".inputs" value="2"></input>
<input class=".inputs" value="2"></input>

<input class=".result" value="0"></input>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in Vue.js or vanilla JS?

Comment: Yes, I tried with some mounted functions and lifecycle hooks and got nothing.

Comment: Can you show us that code?

Comment: I got rid of it because it didn't work. I'm currently looking through VueJS docs for other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you can add a data property that holds values of input. Then watch the array changes to add them and show them in result input. Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    input_array: [2, 2, 2, 2],
  },
  mounted: function() {
    // Update array values
    this.input_array = [5, 3, 4, 6];
  },
  watch: {
    input_array: function(newValue) {
      // Values will be added on every array change
      const total = this.input_array.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
      this.$refs.result.value = total;

    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <input class="inputs" :value="i" v-for='i in input_array'>

  <input class="result" value="0" ref='result'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, @Kalimah. Is there also a way I could grab the values from the inputs themselves instead of the array?

Comment: Although its against vue.js pattern to do this but you can access the DOM using `document.querySelectorAll()`. Or use can add `ref` directive to each input and access it from vue using `this.$refs`